# Doctrine Behaviors fields in Symfony2 auto-generated CRUD

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, crud

I'm starting with Symfony and I have Entity "Post"

```
<?php

namespace My\BackendBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Post
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="text")
     */
    private $text;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    /**
     * Set text
     *
     * @param string $text
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setText($text)
    {
        $this->text = $text;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get text
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getText()
    {
        return $this->text;
    }

    /**
     * Set slug
     *
     * @param string $slug
     * @return Post
     */
    public function setSlug($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }
}
```

I've generated table in database:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

And CRUD panel:

```
app/console doctrine:generate:crud
```

with options:

```
Entity: MyBackendBundle:Post
"write" action: yes
```

But as you can see, I have "slug" field and I want Doctrine to auto-generate it. But default CRUD panel at "/post/new" have inputs for all 3 fields (title, slug and text). And after hours of searching for solution only one I can do is manually delete "slug" input from My/BackendBundle/Form/PostType.php.

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or it's just works like that? Sluggable behavior works good when I'm adding entity manually (by creating new Post() with title and text and doing $manager->flush()).

My /app/config/config.yml file:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
    secret:          %secret%
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:         ~
    fragments:       ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
        # path:     %database_path%

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle: false

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            sluggable: true


# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: %mailer_transport%
    host:      %mailer_host%
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%
    spool:     { type: memory }

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: My\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

If it's normal and I have to do it manually simple confirmation would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app/console doctrine:generate:crud` command use [generate:doctrine:form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_form.html) command which generate fields for all entity properties.

So yes, you must remove unnecessary fields from form OR use more advenced generators like [AdmigeneratorGeneratorBundle](http://symfony2admingenerator.org/).